# Adding error handling to a function that loads data (but also needs to use default values sometimes)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find a non-clunky way to introduce error-handling into function that loads data from a data source. The snag is that the DataSource may (or may not) contain invalid data, and that in the event that a value fails to be parsed, depending on the DataSource's 'revision' either a default value should be used or an error should be generated:

```
class Foo {

    int value_1;
    int value_2;
    //...

    void loadDataFromSource(DataSource source)
    {
        int revision = source.getRevision();
        value_1 = source.parseValue(1);
        value_2 = source.parseValue(2);
        //...
    }
}
```

The function "parseValue()" currently returns a default value if it fails to parse, but as mentioned above, error handling needs to be introduced. I could have "parseValue()" throw exceptions and handle them (depending on DataSource revision), e.g.

```
void loadDataFromSource_NewRevision(DataSource source)
{
    //Exceptions thrown by parseValue() are handled by the caller of this function
    value_1 = source.parseValue(1);
    value_2 = source.parseValue(2);
    //...
}

void loadDataFromSource_OldRevision(DataSource source)
{
    //Exceptions thrown by parseValue() are discarded and default values are used
    try { value_1 = source.parseValue(1); }
    catch(...) { value_1 = 42; }
    try { value_2 = source.parseValue(2); }
    catch(...) { value_2 = -7; }
    //...
}
```

But the code duplication and the entire set-up feels just bad. Same goes for using some kind of flag to tell parseValue() to throw/not-throw exceptions.

```
void loadDataFromSource(DataSource source)
{
    int revision = source.getRevision();
    bool useDefaultValueOnError = revision < 10;
    //Exceptions thrown by parseValue() - if any - are handled by the caller of this function
    value_1 = source.parseValue(1, useDefaultValueOnError, 42);
    value_2 = source.parseValue(2, useDefaultValueOnError, -7);
    //...
}
```

I'd like to avoid the code duplication, but the 'flag' option looks equally unappealing. Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Edit / Small update:
I managed to reduce the number of values, that we need to use a default value for (if it fails to parse in the old revision of the data source) to a mere handful. For those I created a second "parseValueWithDefault" function with a parameter and a "use default-on-error" flag which invokes the original parse function, catches the error and either returns the default or rethrows the exception. Not perfect, but I feel that was the least bad option at this time.

```
int parseValueWithDefault(int valueId, int defaultValue, bool useDefaultOnError)
{
    try 
    {
        return source.parseValue(valueId);
    }
    catch (Exception& e)
    {
        if (useDefaultOnError)
            return defaultValue;
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: use a struct as return value which contains value and error code or use an out-variable for error codes

Comment: you may have parseValue() return boost/std::optional, and then invoke std::optional<>::value_or() on the result ... "value_1 = source.parseValue(1).value_or(42)"

Comment: @kabanus: regarding using exception/no-exception-but-default-value. Older revision of the DataSource are know to have the (occasional) bad values, which we can handle by using a default value. DataSources of the newer revision however should not have any bad values, so any bad values encountered need to be treated as errors.

Comment: @kabanus Yes, unfortunately we need to support handling bad/missing input for the older DataSource revisions (for backwards compatibility), I've been brooding about this thing for several hours now, since the schema will be employed in 50+ classes/functions and re-doing later (again) it would be quite an amout of work.

Comment: @kabanus Thanks, I already had suspected (feared?) that there would be no neat & clean solution to this, but I wanted to give it a shot anyway. Also, how can I move this to Software Engineering?

Comment: @CharonX Use the flag button, and ask for moderator intervention. Say you want to migrate, and why. I've been rebuked that this is indeed on topic here, but these rebukers did not post an answer, and I'm not sure the solution below is what they you're aiming for. In any case, the reason I thought this would be better there since (I think) it is more oriented towards design questions, and may better suit a question on best practices for multiple branches in your project and workflow etc. It doesn't seem to me you have a coding deficit - but it's your choice.

Comment: Isn't that, what [std::optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) was invented for? But it's not entirely clear, which code you can change, or where information (like the revision) is available.

Comment: Can you change parseValue to return default/throw depending on the DataSource revision? I seems to me that would be a logical place to do that logic: DataSource class handles its own revisions internally, and external consumers of the API only get errors in the real error case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suggestion:**

Assuming that the provided code snippets includes the same information that is available, there are a couple of ways to build off of the Old Revision, but it would depend on the exceptions that could be thrown in each case, or if you do a catch for any exception. This answer will simply be about the error handling piece rather than processing values.

```
void loadDataFromSource_OldRevision(DataSource source)
{
    //Exceptions thrown by parseValue() are discarded and default values are used
    try { value_1 = source.parseValue(1); }
    catch(...) { value_1 = 42; }
    try { value_2 = source.parseValue(2); }
    catch(...) { value_2 = -7; }
    //...
}
```

Assuming that you know the exception(s), you have a couple of options moving forward. If you have differing exceptions, then you can specify them directly in two catch statements (as shown below; simplified naming just for an explanation and you can search for specific exceptions).

```
try{
    // parse value
} catch (SomeOldException ex) {
    // give default
} catch (SomeNewException ex) {
    // throw exception
}
```

For using multiple values, you can go towards collecting and iterating over the values in whatever way you decide.

If both revisions throw the same error, or if you need the exception to always be a "Catch All" exception (...), then you could utilize the revision that appears to be available in your DataSource (as shown below).

```
try{
    // parse value
} catch (...) {
    // check the revision number
    //throw exception or provide default value respectively
```

Hope that this helps. And others, please feel free to edit where you see fit. It has been quite some time, since I have used C++ regularly.

There are some other options as well, but I would need a refresher on quite a few things in C++ before I could really talk about them as an answer. As you get more revisions/default value corrections, it may be beneficial to look into some other concepts that have been beneficial in other languages as well. Such as, Abstract Classes, Dependency Injection, or anything that would help with the separation of concerns in your objects.